# how to specify a package or namespace for `rlang::exec`?

Tags: r, rlang

I am trying to write a function (within a package) which involves allowing the user to specify a function from a specific package to execute and provide additional arguments for that function.

I can do this in two steps with `rlang::call2` as follows:

```
# `my_pkg` = "foo" (user-input)
# `my_fun` = "bar" (user-input)
# `args` is a named list (user-input)

the_call <- rlang::call2(.fn = my_fun , !!!args , .ns = my_pkg)
base::eval(the_call)
```

I have a feeling that the "correct" way to do this is to just use `rlang::exec`, but `rlang::exec` does not have a `.ns` argument like `rlang::call2` does. Instead, it has an `.env` argument.

**How do you specify the package (or namespace) of a function to `rlang::exec`?** The `.env` argument to `rlang::exec` doesn't appear to be the answer, because the user should be able to specify a function in a specific package (that is installed) without first loading that package.

Or is `rlang::exec` not meant for this purpose?

Comment: may I ask what's wrong with your two-step approach?

Comment: nothing. But then what is the point of `rlang::exec`?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```r
real_fun <- get(my_fun, envir=as.environment(paste0("package:", my_pkg)))
rlang::exec(real_fun, !!!args)
```

Since `"packagename::functionname"` (string) cannot be passed to `rlang::exec`, we can pass the real function. This can be retrieved by using `get` and passing a particular environment (from a package namespace, as above).

(This doesn't alleviate the need for two expressions to effect the `exec`, but it does allow one to use `exec` directly.)